# JTable Selection with the help of a combobox?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a combobox with values of 1 to 5 and a JTable of 5X5... Whenever a select a value from combobox corresponding entire column of the JTable has to get selected... how do I proceed with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First  you need to configure your table to allow for column selection:

```
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed( true );
table.setRowSelectionAllowed( false );
```

Then for the combo box you need to add an ActionListener to select the column based on the selected item index:

```
table.setColumnSelectionInverval(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get value of selected item in combobox as `comboBox.getSelectedItem()` and parse it to integer and then call following method:

```
public void getSelected(int comboBoxValue){
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

    // The following column selection method works 
    // only if these properties are set
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);

    table.setColumnSelectionInterval(comboBoxValue, comboBoxValue);
}
```